# Why is LaTeX failing to generate list of algorithms with algorithm2e?

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, errors, algorithms, algorithm2e

I have 3 algorithms in my thesis (2 in appendix and 1 in a chapter). I have the package `algorithm2e` loaded in the preamble. I successfully generate a list of figures and list of tables, however, list of algorithms is failing with a seemingly unrelated error *printed on the PDF* (under the heading "List of Algorithms") which says:

```
LaTeX Font Warning:  Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

The class that I'm using is [this thesis class](https://ctan.org/pkg/msu-thesis?lang=en).

I tried to produce an MWE, however, when I use the same document class and try in another sample tex file, the list of algorithms is correctly generated. Therefore, something in my thesis is messing up the generation of list of algorithms (and not figures and tables) AND is somehow related to fonts. I cannot understand this error message at all or how to fix it. Since I cannot copy my entire thesis here and MWE is working just fine when I use the same class, algorithm package, and algorithms, I have resorted to providing the following code to hint at what I'm doing in thesis document (which isn't working):

```
\documentclass[PhD]{msu-thesis}
...
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,algochapter]{algorithm2e}

...

\clearpage
\SingleSpacing
\tableofcontents*
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listofalgorithms

...

\appendices
\input{chapters/APPENDICES}
\backmatter
\makebibliographypage
\SingleSpacing

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way I can determine what is causing the list of algorithms to fail with this error message printed in the PDF? I have tried looking in the logs but there's no font-related errors or anything that stands out. I looked at other related questions however nothing I've tried works in my case.

Comment: That's not an error, but a simple warning. Please, make a code example that does not depend on external files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer here for anyone who might be plagued by the same warning message. In my particular case, the problem was an `acronyms.tex` file that I had included right after the `\mainmatter`:

```
\makeglossaries

\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
%% packages end here

%% author, title, date start here

%\title{\textbf{blah}}
\title{\textbf{blah}}
\author{name}
\fieldofstudy{Wizadary}
\dedication{This thesis is dedicated to <someone>.}
\date{2002}

%% author, title, date end here

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%
\maketitlepage
%
\input{chapters/ch0-ABSTRACT}
%
\clearpage
\makecopyrightpage
% \makededicationpage
%
\clearpage
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\DoubleSpacing
I bla bla
%
\clearpage
\SingleSpacing
\tableofcontents*
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listofalgorithms

\clearpage


%% chapters start here

\mainmatter
\input{acronyms}
\input{chapters/ch1-wht}
...
\input{chapters/ch9-who}
% chapters end here
```

I moved the `acronyms.tex` and that fixed the error:

```
\makeglossaries
\input{acronyms}
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
%% packages end here

%% author, title, date start here

%\title{\textbf{blah}}
\title{\textbf{blah}}
\author{name}
\fieldofstudy{Wizadary}
\dedication{This thesis is dedicated to <someone>.}
\date{2002}

%% author, title, date end here

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%
\maketitlepage
%
\input{chapters/ch0-ABSTRACT}
%
\clearpage
\makecopyrightpage
% \makededicationpage
%
\clearpage
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\DoubleSpacing
I bla bla
%
\clearpage
\SingleSpacing
\tableofcontents*
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listofalgorithms

\clearpage


%% chapters start here

\mainmatter

\input{chapters/ch1-wht}
...
\input{chapters/ch9-who}
% chapters end here
```

I have no idea why this was producing an error and why the move of acronyms.tex mattered for the list of algorithms. May be someone else can explain that here.